# text to speech arabic in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, package, text-to-speech

I am searching for Text to speech package in flutter and I found this one [flutter_tts](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tts)
but its not supporting Arabic language is there any way to Add Arabic language or any other package that Supports Arabic language ?

Comment: Did you find any?

Answer (score 0):

Use Flutter [speech_to_text](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text) package.

to change language, localeId = the ID of the Arabic language on this device:

```
var locales = await speech.locales();

// Some UI or other code to select a locale from the list
// resulting in an index, selectedLocale

var selectedLocale = locales[selectedLocale];
speech.listen(
    onResult: resultListener,
    localeId: selectedLocale.localeId,
    );
```

Comment: I don't want Speech to text I want Text to Speech